# Expected value of a selection process

Tags: statistics, algorithms, expected-value, sampling

The setting of my problem is as follows:

I have a large pool of random variables $X_1,...., X_n$ which are i.i.d, which I'll refer to as ***nodes***.

At each round of my random process I select by random $N << n$ nodes $X_{p_1}, ..., X_{p_N} $ which we'll be referred to as ***participants***.
I also select randomly one extra node independently from the participants. Let this node be called ***leader***.

At each round, the selected leader performs some selection process where it votes for a single participant.
The selection is dependent on the value of the *leader* node and nothing else (e.g. the leader selects the participant $X_{p_i}$ with value "closest" to its own).

Can I say anything about the expected value $\mathbf{E}[X_{p_i}]$ where $X_{p_i}$ is the selected participant.

The intuition is that since every node has equal chance to become a *leader* or a *participant* the expected value will be that of the shared distribution of each node.
However, I can't formulate the conditions on the selection process that support that.

Comment: How is $p_i$ related to $X_i$?

Comment: Thanks @d.k.o - rephrased. hope it's clearer